# What's the best way of choosing ports in udp programming with sockets?

Tags: sockets, udp, port

Suppose the language chosen is C++, the udp programming happens on a single computer and we have a client program as well as a server program. Most of the examples I can find online choose literal numbers, like 4001 and 4002, as the ports' values. But in practice, the chosen ports might already be occupied and for security reasons, the ports have to be determined at runtime. If, for example, the server's port has already been dynamically determined, then how is the client program supposed to know about that?

As far as I can imagine, I might have to create a local file to dynamically update the info, but I don't know if it's the right way. And, even if this method works, it won't work for the situation where the udp program involves two computers...

Comment: There's a faily old service called "portmapper" that you can register your listening socket with, under a preestablished name, and be able to find and connect to it that way. This is for Linux/Unix.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Thank you! That works for udp programs running between two computers, right? So a local file is still needed for single-computer udp programs?

Comment: You can still use the portmapper for clients and servers on the same host.

Comment: This falls under the realm of "service discovery", of which there are various protocols/techniques for it. The server registers itself in a place where the client can then query. Many different ways to handle that. Of course, the simplest solution may be to just have the server output its port onscreen, and then let the client take the port to use from the user